# Getting the frequency of a certain value in each column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame in which all the missing values are denoted with `?`. I need the count of `?` per each column.

A method that I tried was:

```
mydata.replace('?','')
mydata.isnull().sum()
```

that returns:

```
A1     0
A2     0
A3     0
A4     0
A5     0
A6     0
...
A16    0
dtype: int64
```

which should not be the case because there are `?` in the CSV file that I got my data from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare all values with `?` and get occurencies by `sum` of `True` values:

```
out = (mydata == '?').sum()
```

Similar:

```
out = mydata.eq('?').sum()
```

---

In your solution first should be replaced `?` to `NaN` and then chain together:

```
out = mydata.replace('?',np.nan).isnull().sum()
```

Also is possible replace `?` to missing values in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) by parameter `na_values='?'`:

```
mydata = pd.read_csv(file, na_values='?')

out = mydata.isnull().sum()
```